# Gulp.js won't reload plain CSS

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-watch

This is my Gulpfile:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    watch        = require('gulp-watch'),
    livereload   = require('gulp-livereload');


gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch('./css/**/*.css', ['css']).on('change', livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch('./js/**/*.js', ['js']).on('change', livereload.changed);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.php').on('change', livereload.changed);
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'watch']);
```

It will reload the CSS once and then crash with this error:

```
[15:30:13] style.css was reloaded.
[15:30:13] Task 'css' is not in your gulpfile
[15:30:13] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

Not sure what to make of this, anyone had similar issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a task with things you want to do with this CSS

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('./css/**/*.css')
           .pipe(livereload());
});
```

then watch this file, if changed, run the task again.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch('./css/**/*.css', ['css']);
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'watch']);
```